# SQL Scope of SELECT

Tags: sql, select, db2

How do you extend the scope of a SELECT statement so that the Alias will be recognizable throughout the WHERE?

I am using DB2 v5.

For example

```
UPDATE 
    DB1.myTable t1
SET 
    t1.col2table1 = (SELECT col2table2 as t2 FROM DB1.table2
WHERE 
    (col3table2 = 'somevalue') AND (t1.col1table1 = t2.col1table2))
```

I am getting the error - Column qualifier or table T2 undefined.

Comment: t2 is a column alias but you're trying to use it like a table alias in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need the table alias *by the table*:

```
UPDATE DB1.myTable t1
    SET t1.col2table1 = (SELECT col2table2
                         FROM DB1.table2 t2
-----------------------------------------^
                         WHERE (t2.col3table2 = 'somevalue') AND
                               (t1.col1table1 = t2.col1table2)
                        ) ;
```

When using correlated subqueries, I strongly encourage you to qualify *all* column names.  This can prevent future code bugs.

EDIT:

You can add:

```
where exists (SELECT 1
              FROM DB1.table2 t2
              WHERE (t2.col3table2 = 'somevalue') AND
                    (t1.col1table1 = t2.col1table2)
             )
```

Comment: Result of SELECT more than one row.

Comment: You now have a different error.  I don't know how you intend to convert multiple rows to a single row, but one way is to sue `select max(col2table2)` in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks.  Very close to solution now. 
I just need an else which will leave the record alone if false.

Answer (score 0):

With an inner join

```
UPDATE 
    DB1.myTable t1
INNER JOIN 
    DB1.table2 t2 on t1.col1table1 = t2.col1table2
SET 
    t1.col2table1 = t2.col2table2
WHERE 
    (t2.col3table2 = 'somevalue')
```

Comment: Keyword JOIN not expected. Valid tokens: SET.